# Run kibana in k8s but get `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'plugins/kibana/local_application_service'`

Tags: kubernetes, kibana-7

I run an es cluster in my k8s cluster, then I installed kibana, but get error:

```
    ERROR in ./x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/dashboard_viewer.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'plugins/kibana/local_application_service' in '/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public'
```

ES cluster is running well. But kibana cannot start up. I tried 3 times to reinstall it, but not work.
Please help me, thanks.

- versions: es -> 7.8.0, kibana -> 7.8.0
- yamls

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: es
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5601
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: kibana
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: es
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: kibana:7.8.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: '1'
          requests:
            cpu: '0.1'
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
          value: 'http://es-node1:9200 http://es-node2:9200'
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
```

- kibana logs

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:09:50Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":6,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: apm_oss"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:09:50Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":6,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:10:46Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":6,"message":"Plugin \"visTypeXy\" is disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:10:46Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":6,"message":"Plugin \"endpoint\" is disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:10:46Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":6,"message":"Plugin \"ingestManager\" is disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:10:46Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":6,"message":"Plugin \"lists\" is disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:10Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":6,"message":"Setting up [94] plugins: [taskManager,licensing,observability,eventLog,encryptedSavedObjects,code,usageCollection,ossTelemetry,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetry,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaLegacy,devTools,translations,uiActions,statusPage,share,mapsLegacy,mapsLegacyLicensing,newsfeed,kibanaUtils,kibanaReact,inspector,embeddable,advancedUiActions,embeddableEnhanced,drilldowns,indexPatternManagement,esUiShared,discover,charts,bfetch,expressions,data,home,cloud,apm_oss,console,consoleExtensions,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,upgradeAssistant,reporting,licenseManagement,indexManagement,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,watcher,advancedSettings,telemetryManagementSection,fileUpload,dataEnhanced,visualizations,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeseries,rollup,visTypeTimelion,features,security,snapshotRestore,transform,ingestPipelines,canvas,visTypeTable,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeMetric,visTypeMarkdown,inputControlVis,navigation,lens,graph,maps,savedObjects,visualize,dashboard,dashboardEnhanced,savedObjectsManagement,spaces,actions,case,alerting,alertingBuiltins,triggers_actions_ui,infra,monitoring,logstash,uptime,ml,siem,apm]"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:10Z","tags":["warning","plugins","encryptedSavedObjects","config"],"pid":6,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey. To be able to decrypt encrypted saved objects attributes after restart, please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["warning","plugins","security","config"],"pid":6,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in kibana.yml"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["warning","plugins","security","config"],"pid":6,"message":"Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["warning","plugins","actions","actions"],"pid":6,"message":"APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["warning","plugins","alerting","plugins","alerting"],"pid":6,"message":"APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["info","plugins","monitoring","monitoring"],"pid":6,"message":"config sourced from: production cluster"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["warning","plugins","monitoring","monitoring"],"pid":6,"message":"X-Pack Monitoring Cluster Alerts will not be available: undefined"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":6,"message":"Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations..."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["info","plugins","crossClusterReplication"],"pid":6,"message":"Your basic license does not support crossClusterReplication. Please upgrade your license."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["info","plugins","watcher"],"pid":6,"message":"Your basic license does not support watcher. Please upgrade your license."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:11Z","tags":["info","plugins","monitoring","monitoring","kibana-monitoring"],"pid":6,"message":"Starting monitoring stats collection"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:12Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":6,"message":"Starting saved objects migrations"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:12Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":6,"message":"Starting [72] plugins: [taskManager,licensing,observability,eventLog,encryptedSavedObjects,code,usageCollection,ossTelemetry,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetry,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaLegacy,translations,share,discover,bfetch,expressions,data,home,cloud,apm_oss,console,consoleExtensions,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,upgradeAssistant,reporting,licenseManagement,indexManagement,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,watcher,advancedSettings,fileUpload,dataEnhanced,visualizations,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeseries,rollup,visTypeTimelion,features,security,snapshotRestore,transform,ingestPipelines,canvas,visTypeTable,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeMetric,visTypeMarkdown,inputControlVis,lens,graph,visualize,dashboard,savedObjectsManagement,spaces,actions,case,alerting,alertingBuiltins,infra,monitoring,logstash,uptime,ml,siem,apm]"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:36Z","tags":["warning","saved-objects"],"pid":6,"message":"Saved Objects uninitialized because the Kibana plugin is disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:11:44Z","tags":["info","optimize"],"pid":6,"message":"Optimizing and caching bundles for dashboardViewer and maps. This may take a few minutes"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:14:33Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":6,"message":"{ Error: Optimizations failure.\n   1660 modules\n    \n    ERROR in ./x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/dashboard_viewer.js\n    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'plugins/kibana/local_application_service' in '/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public'\n\n    at FsOptimizer.failedStatsToError (/usr/share/kibana/src/optimize/base_optimizer.js:436:26)\n    at compiler.run (/usr/share/kibana/src/optimize/fs_optimizer.js:43:26)\n    at finalCallback (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)\n    at hooks.done.callAsync.err (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:273:13)\n    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)\n    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)\n    at onCompiled (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:271:21)\n    at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:681:15)\n    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)\n    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)\n    at compilation.seal.err (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:678:31)\n    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)\n    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)\n    at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35)\n    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] 
(eval at create (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)\n    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)\n  cause:\n   { Error: Optimizations failure.\n      1660 modules\n       \n       ERROR in ./x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/dashboard_viewer.js\n       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'plugins/kibana/local_application_service' in '/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public'\n   \n       at FsOptimizer.failedStatsToError (/usr/share/kibana/src/optimize/base_optimizer.js:436:26)\n       at compiler.run (/usr/share/kibana/src/optimize/fs_optimizer.js:43:26)\n       at finalCallback (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)\n       at hooks.done.callAsync.err (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:273:13)\n       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)\n       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)\n       at onCompiled (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:271:21)\n       at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:681:15)\n       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)\n       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)\n       at compilation.seal.err (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:678:31)\n       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)\n       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/share/kib
ana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)\n       at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35)\n       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)\n       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)\n     data:\n      { errors: [Array],\n        warnings: [],\n        version: '4.41.5',\n        hash: 'a43bf197984c335f4355',\n        time: 160392,\n        builtAt: 1593425672528,\n        publicPath: '__REPLACE_WITH_PUBLIC_PATH__',\n        outputPath: '/usr/share/kibana/optimize/bundles',\n        assetsByChunkName: [Object],\n        assets: [Array],\n        filteredAssets: 0,\n        entrypoints: [Object],\n        namedChunkGroups: [Object],\n        chunks: [Array],\n        modules: [Array],\n        filteredModules: 0,\n        logging: [Object],\n        children: [Array] },\n     isBoom: true,\n     isServer: true,\n     output: { statusCode: 500, payload: [Object], headers: {} },\n     reformat: [Function],\n     typeof: [Function: internal] },\n  isOperational: true,\n  data:\n   { errors:\n      [ './x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/dashboard_viewer.js\\nModule not found: Error: Can\\'t resolve \\'plugins/kibana/local_application_service\\' in \\'/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public\\'\\nresolve \\'plugins/kibana/local_application_service\\' in \\'/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public\\'\\n  Parsed request is a module\\n  using description file: /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/package.json (relative path: ./legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public)\\n    Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n    resolve as module\\n      /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/webpackShims doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/share
/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/webpackShims doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/webpackShims doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/webpackShims doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/webpackShims doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/share/webpackShims doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/webpackShims doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /webpackShims doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      looking for modules in /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims\\n        using description file: /usr/share/kibana/package.json (relative path: ./webpackShims)\\n          Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n          using description file: /usr/share/kibana/package.json (relative path: ./webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service)\\n            no extension\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n            .js\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.js doesn\\'t exist\\n            .ts\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.ts doesn\\'t exist\\n            .tsx\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.tsx doesn\\'t exist\\n            .json\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.json doesn\\'t exist\\n            as directory\\n              /usr/share/kibana
/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n      looking for modules in /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims\\n        using description file: /usr/share/kibana/package.json (relative path: ./webpackShims)\\n          Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n          using description file: /usr/share/kibana/package.json (relative path: ./webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service)\\n            no extension\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n            .js\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.js doesn\\'t exist\\n            .ts\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.ts doesn\\'t exist\\n            .tsx\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.tsx doesn\\'t exist\\n            .json\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.json doesn\\'t exist\\n            as directory\\n              /usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n      /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/node_modules doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/node_modules doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/node_modules doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/node_modules doesn\\'t exist or is not a directo
ry\\n      /usr/share/node_modules doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /usr/node_modules doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      /node_modules doesn\\'t exist or is not a directory\\n      looking for modules in /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules\\n        using description file: /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)\\n          Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n      looking for modules in /usr/share/kibana/node_modules\\n        using description file: /usr/share/kibana/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)\\n          Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n          using description file: /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service)\\n            no extension\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n          using description file: /usr/share/kibana/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service)\\n            no extension\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n            .js\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n            .js\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.js doesn\\'t exist\\n            .ts\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.js doesn\\'t exist\\n            .ts\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/s
hare/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.ts doesn\\'t exist\\n            .tsx\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.ts doesn\\'t exist\\n            .tsx\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.tsx doesn\\'t exist\\n            .json\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.tsx doesn\\'t exist\\n            .json\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.json doesn\\'t exist\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.json doesn\\'t exist\\n            as directory\\n              /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n            as directory\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n      looking for modules in /usr/share/kibana/node_modules\\n        using description file: /usr/share/kibana/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)\\n          Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n          using description file: /usr/share/kibana/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service)\\n            no extension\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n            .js\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/no
de_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.js doesn\\'t exist\\n            .ts\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.ts doesn\\'t exist\\n            .tsx\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.tsx doesn\\'t exist\\n            .json\\n              Field \\'browser\\' doesn\\'t contain a valid alias configuration\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.json doesn\\'t exist\\n            as directory\\n              /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service doesn\\'t exist\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/webpackShims]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/webpackShims]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/webpackShims]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/webpackShims]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/webpackShims]\\n[/usr/share/webpackShims]\\n[/usr/webpackShims]\\n[/webpackShims]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.js]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.ts]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.tsx]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/webpackShims/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.json]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/node_modules]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/node_modules]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/node_modules]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/node_modules]\\n[/usr/share/node_modules]\\n[/usr/node_modules]\\n[/node_modules]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/
local_application_service]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.js]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.js]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.ts]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.ts]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.tsx]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.tsx]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.json]\\n[/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/plugins/kibana/local_application_service.json]\\n @ ./x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/dashboard_viewer.js 37:33-84\\n @ ./optimize/bundles/dashboardViewer.entry.js' ],\n     warnings: [],\n     version: '4.41.5',\n     hash: 'a43bf197984c335f4355',\n     time: 160392,\n     builtAt: 1593425672528,\n     publicPath: '__REPLACE_WITH_PUBLIC_PATH__',\n     outputPath: '/usr/share/kibana/optimize/bundles',\n     assetsByChunkName:\n      { commons: [Array],\n        dark_theme: [Array],\n        dashboardViewer: [Array],\n        light_theme: [Array],\n        maps: [Array] },\n     assets:\n      [ [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object] ],\n     filteredAssets: 0,\n     entrypoints:\n      { dashboardViewer: [Object],\n        maps: [Object],\n        light_theme: [Object],\n        dark_theme: [Object] },\n     namedChunkGroups:\n      { dashboardViewer: [Object],\n        maps: [Object],\n        light_theme: [Object],\n        dark_theme: [Object] },\n     chunks:\n      [ [Object],\n        [Object],\n    
    [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object] ],\n     modules:\n      [ [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n                [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        ... 1560 more
 items ],\n     filteredModules: 0,\n     logging: { 'webpack.buildChunkGraph.visitModules': [Object] },\n     children:\n      [ [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object],\n        [Object] ] },\n  isBoom: true,\n  isServer: true,\n  output:\n   { statusCode: 500,\n     payload:\n      { statusCode: 500,\n        error: 'Internal Server Error',\n        message: 'An internal server error occurred' },\n     headers: {} },\n  reformat: [Function],\n  typeof: [Function: internal] }"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:14:33Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":6,"message":"Stopping all plugins."}

...

{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:14:33Z","tags":["info","plugins","licensing"],"pid":6,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-29T10:14:33Z","tags":["info","plugins","taskManager"],"pid":6,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
    
    ERROR in ./x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public/dashboard_viewer.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'plugins/kibana/local_application_service' in '/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/legacy/plugins/dashboard_mode/public'
```

- files in kibana pod

```
pwd: /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins
ls:
bash-4.2$ ls
actions              case                       data_enhanced            features                    infra               lists                  observability    searchprofiler    telemetry_collection_xpack  watcher
advanced_ui_actions  cloud                      drilldowns               file_upload                 ingest_manager      logstash               oss_telemetry    security          transform
alerting             code                       embeddable_enhanced      graph                       ingest_pipelines    maps                   painless_lab     siem              translations
alerting_builtins    console_extensions         encrypted_saved_objects  grokdebugger                lens                maps_legacy_licensing  remote_clusters  snapshot_restore  triggers_actions_ui
apm                  cross_cluster_replication  endpoint                 index_lifecycle_management  license_management  ml                     reporting        spaces            upgrade_assistant
canvas               dashboard_enhanced         event_log                index_management            licensing           monitoring             rollup           task_manager      uptime
```

[image: dashboard_viewer.js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is due to

```
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
          value: 'http://es-node1:9200 http://es-node2:9200'
```

Try leaving only one of the es nodes and it will be ok. For instance:

```
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
          value: 'http://es-node1:9200'
```

For more info on the proper syntax and its challenges - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/syntax-to-specify-multiple-hosts-using-elasticsearch-hosts-env/221306/8

Comment: Thanks! I tried this way, It's ok to run now. I thought `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS` can be an array ...